# Automating sshfs not working

Tags: bash, sshfs

I want to mount a remote directory and I want to automate this. So I write below script which not working properly.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn sshfs vedams@192.168.5.109:/home/user /mnt/remote
expect "assword:"
send "myPassword\r"
```

When I run the above script and if check `ls /mnt/remote`, it is giving below error:

```
ls: cannot access /mnt/remote: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

I used `sshpass` but not working:

```
sshpass -p myPassword sshfs user@192.168.5.109:/home/user /mnt/remote
```

Shell blocked and getting the same error.

Note: If I run `sshpass -p vedams123 sshfs vedams@192.168.5.109:/home/user /mnt/remote`, working withour any problem.

Comment: Same here, sshfs command on command prompt works, the same one in a bash script doesn't. If you add -f at the end of sshfs command then it works in script but stops the script from further execution.

Comment: @zzart passwordless login (keyfiles) would work and skip the trouble of having a clear text password in a script file.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there is a stale session in your intended target directory. You can clear the session with

```
fusermount -u /mnt/remote
```

where `/mnt/remote` is whichever your local mount file path is set to.

Thanks to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215009/28280